# Find child H3 and check if has value

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am looking to use `jQuery` to view a bunch of `<div>` elements which all have the same class name, and check to see if the `h3` within these `<div>` elements has any content. I was thinking this would work (as below) but its not... what am I doing wrong?

```
$('.wrapperDIV').each(function (i) {
    if( $(this).closest('h3').val().length == 0 ) {
        $(this).addClass('.hideME');
    }
});
```

Markup is:

```html
<div class="wrapperDIV">
  <span class="ItemNo">5.</span>
     <a href="#" title="Read more about "><img src="" title="" alt=""></a>
        <h3></h3>
        <div class="composer-button">
        <a href="#" class="read-more" title="Read more about ">Read more</a>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: not sure why you are using `closest('h3')`, try `find('h3')`

Comment: ok - thanks - find worked... but it hides them alll...? not just ones with empty H3... is val().length == 0 not the way to test content within the <h3></h3> tags?

Comment: OK     if( $(this).find('h3').is(':empty') ) {  works

Comment: Thanks for the note re: using FIND

Answer (score 0):

Try to use `.find('h3')` instead of `.closest('h3')`.

Also when using `.addClass()` you dont need to include the dot.

```
$('.wrapperDIV').each(function (i) {
    if( $(this).find('h3').val().empty()) {
        $(this).addClass('hideME');
    }
 });
```

```
<div class="wrapperDIV">
    <span class="ItemNo">5.</span>
    <a href="#" title="Read more about "><img src="" title="" alt=""></a>
    <h3></h3>
    <div class="composer-button"><a href="#" class="read-more" title="Read more about ">Read more</a></div>
</div>
```

This should solve your problem.

For more info, read this
[post](https://www.codecademy.com/forum_questions/5553631d9113cbb1b9000458?locale=en) or the jQuery [.addClass()](https://api.jquery.com/addClass/) Documentation.

Answer (score 0):

Try to use get text instead of value

```
$('.wrapperDIV').each(function (i) {
   if( $(this).find('h3').text() === "" ) {
      $(this).addClass('.hideME');
   }
});
```

```html
<div class="wrapperDIV">
    <span class="ItemNo">5.</span>
    <a href="#" title="Read more about "><img src="" title="" alt=""></a>
    <h3></h3>
    <div class="composer-button"><a href="#" class="read-more" title="Read more about ">Read more</a></div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You may try this workable code in vanilla JavaScript:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>test1</title>
    <script>
        window.onload = function(){
            let div = document.getElementsByClassName('wrapperDIV');
            let ch = div[0].children;

            for(let i=0;i<ch.length; i++){
                if ( ch[i].tagName=='H3' ){
                    let text = ch[i].textContent;
                    if (!text) console.log('It\'s h3 without text')
                } 
            }
        }
    </script>
</head>
<body>
    <div class="wrapperDIV">
        <span class="ItemNo">5.</span>
        <a href="#" title="Read more about "><img src="" title="" alt=""></a>
            <h3></h3>
            <div class="composer-button">
            <a href="#" class="read-more" title="Read more about ">Read more</a>
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

In jQuery you may use the code as under:

```
    $(document).ready(function(){
        let h3 = $(".wrapperDIV > h3");
        if ( !h3.textContent ) console.log('h3 has no text contents');
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve this effect using CSS alone, by using the `:empty` pseudo-class:

```
.wrapperDIV h3:empty {
  display: none;
}
```

---

**Further Reading:**

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:empty